# Proving that no natural number is equinumerous to a proper subset of itself.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that no natural number is equinumerous to a proper subset of itself.

Let $f$ be a mapping from $k^+$ into $k^+$, where $k.k^+\in \Bbb{N}$. My book says

> If the set $k$ is not closed under $f$, then $f(p)=k$ **for some number $p$ less than $k$**.

I wonder why $p$ has to be less than $k$. If $k$ is not closed under $f$, it just means that the image of at lest one element in $k$ does not belong to $k$. For that to remain true, the inverse image of $k$ need not be less than $k$! It can also be $k$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I suppose that the mapping $f$ must be from $k$ to $k^{+}$, i.e. $k+1$.

Comment: As per comment below (@Marc van Leeuwen) the number $k$, "modelled" as a set, is $k = \{ 0, 1, k-1 \}$ and has $k$ elements. Thus, $k+1 = k \cup \{ k \}$ has $k+1$ elements. We have that $k \in k+1$ but $k \notin k$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA- Thanks! That answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is always confusing to consider numbers as sets, but I suppose that here $k=\{\, p\in\Bbb N\mid p<k\,\}$ and $k^+=k+1=k\cup\{k\}$. Then $f$ being a map to $k^+$, every image under $f$ is either an element of $k$ or equal to $k$. Closure of $k$ under $f$ means $\forall p\in k:f(p)\in k$, and so non-closure of $k$ under $f$ means $\exists p\in k:f(p)\notin k$. But that just means $\exists p\in k:f(p)=k$, as stated. There is no consideration involved of the inverse image of $\{k\}$ (which indeed might contain the element $k$).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the mistake I was making.